# How to fix contract violation errors in scheme DrRacket?

Tags: list, scheme, racket

```
(define is1?
  (lambda (tuple)
    (if (and (= 2 (length tuple))
             (= 1 (- (cadr tuple) (car tuple)))
             (list? tuple))
        #t
        #f)))

(define greenlist?
  (lambda (x) (andmap is1? x)))

(greenlist? '((2 4 6) (5 6) (1 2)))
(greenlist? '(3 4 5 6))
```

The second command: `(greenlist? '(3 4 5 6))` returns an error when it should return false.
Instead I get this error:

> length: contract violation
>   expected: list?
>   given: 3

What should I change in my code so it returns false instead of an error?

Here is the definition of a greenlist:

> A greenlist is a non-empty list of pairs of integers where a pair of
>   integers is a list of exactly two integers and where each pair `'( x y)`  has the property that y – x  = 1.
>
> Example: `'((5 6) (3 4) (2 3) (-5 -4))` is a greenlist.

Comment: Please use an editor that properly indents the code, you shouldn't write lines with only a closing bracket. See my answer, that's the proper way to format code in Scheme.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that *the order of the conditions matters*: in an `and` expression the conditions are evaluated in left-to-right order, if one condition is `false` then the other conditions are skipped (short-circuit evaluation).

Your input is a list of lists, so you should test *first* if the current element is an actual list - otherwise you'll attempt to take the `length` of an object which isn't a list (the number `3` in your example), which is an error.

By the way: it's possible to simplify the code, you don't actually need to use an `if`, just return the value of the condition:

```
(define is1?
  (lambda (tuple)
    (and (list? tuple) ; you must ask this first!
         (= 2 (length tuple))
         (= 1 (- (cadr tuple) (car tuple))))))
```

Comment: Thank you, it works.
I get the same error when I run (greenlist? "green apples" ) when I should get false.
How can I make it return false instead of getting an error?

Comment: Then you also need to check if the input is a list, in the greenlist? function. But to be honest you shouldn’t be checking if the types are correct, if the user passes the wrong type it’s not your problem, this is a dynamically typed language and you just don’t have to worry about checking for those errors. For example, what if the input is ‘((”x” “y”)) ? That would be yet another case to check.

Comment: One could use `define/contract` to assert that `tuple` is a `(listof int?)`